# How to rename a file while copying into another directory in python?

Tags: python, rename, shutil, copying

I would like to copy a file from one directory to another with simultaneously renaming the file in python. The "file" need to be copied as "new-file" without renaming the file in source directory. I tried something like this;

```
     import shutil,os
     src_path="path of source directory"
     dst="path of destination directory"
     for file in os.listdir(src):
         file_path=os.path.join(src_path,file)
          shutil.copy(file_path,dst/"new"+'-'+file)
```

However this is not working. I know by using os.rename() module, it can be renamed after copying. However i have files with similar names which will be replacing the already copied files in order to avoid which i need to rename each file as "new-file" along with copying itself.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to divide strings -- `dst/"new"`

Comment: And you evidently know how to use `os.path.join` because you are using it on the previous line.

Comment: Check out the stuff in https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html !

Comment: @Ben I've posted an answer with minimal bugfix of the original code, but it would be good to have an answer with pathlib also - maybe you could post one?

Comment: You use it to determine the new name,  including the path. If you don't understand how, then you look at the previous line of your own code, where you did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt to join strings together using `dst/"new"` will not work because this is attempting to perform a division.  You have correctly used `os.path.join` when creating the full path for the source file, and you simply need to do the same thing with the destination file also.

```
import shutil
import os

src_path = "path of source directory"
dst = "path of destination directory"

for file in os.listdir(src_path):
    file_path = os.path.join(src_path, file)
    shutil.copy(file_path, os.path.join(dst, "new-" + file))
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want to manipulate paths in Python 3, I feel like you should reach for [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Here's a solution that uses `shututil`'s [`copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) with a custom copy function that uses `pathlib`. It's nice because it also works with nested directories - note that it doesn't rename directories, only files:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


def copy_and_rename(src: str, dst: str):
    """copy and rename a file as new-<name>"""
    new_name = "new-" + Path(dst).name
    new_dst = Path(dst).with_name(new_name)
    shutil.copy2(src, new_dst)


shutil.copytree(
    "./copy-from-me", "./copy-to-me", copy_function=copy_and_rename, dirs_exist_ok=True
)
```

Here's an example of running this:

```
$ tree copy-from-me
copy-from-me
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
└── nested
    └── 3.txt

$ tree copy-to-me
copy-to-me
├── nested
│   └── new-3.txt
├── new-1.txt
└── new-2.txt
```